# C++17 if statement with initializer, initializer assign nullptr, how to handle condition?

Tags: c++, c++17

I am trying to use C++17 if statement with initializer in real code, but below code behavior makes me confused with this new feature.

```
#include <iostream>

struct call
{
public:
    bool isLive()
    {
        return true;
    }
};

call* createCall()
{
    return nullptr;
}

int main()
{
    if (auto call = createCall(); call->isLive())
    {
        std::cout << "if print" << '\n';
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "else print" << '\n';
    }
}
```

The output is:
**if print**

And if I change return value of call::isLive() to false, then output is:
**else print**

As I expected, since createCall() returns nullptr, the code should crash if not add null protection before call call->isLive(). Why call->isLive() can be still called successfully?

When I next time use this feature, need I add the seemingly redundant null protection like this?

```
if (auto call = createCall(); call && call->isLive())
```

Comment: Calling a method on a null class pointer causes undefined behavior, which can have any effect, including not crashing. In practice, if you don't read any member variables in the method, it may not crash. `call && call->isLive()` is the right solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would get the same undefined behavior without the `if`:

```
auto call = createCall();
call->isLive();
```

This only appears to work, because the method is not actually using the `this` pointer (but in any case it is wrong).

In

```
if (auto call = createCall(); call->isLive())
```

the `auto call = createCall();` is not part of the condition. If you want to check if `call` is not `nullptr` you have to make that part of the condition:

```
if (auto call = createCall(); call && call->isLive()) {
     // ...
}
```